# How to remove associations from the output in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a classMethod defined for the Model User

```
// model user.js
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        User.belongsToMany(models.project, {through: 'user_project', foreignKey: 'user_id', otherKey: 'project_id'})
    }
}
```

From a route in Express i then query for the projects of this user and output it as JSON

```
user.getProjects({
    attributes: ['id', 'title'],
})
.then(function(projects) {
    res.json(projects)
})
```

This works fine, except for the fact the output also contains the `user_project` property which I would like to hide/omit/remove

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Some project",
    "user_project": {
       "created_at": "2017-02-16T22:52:48.000Z",
       "updated_at": "2017-02-16T22:52:48.000Z",
       "project_id": 8,
       "user_id": 5
     }
  },
  //etc.
```

I have tried various exclude and include statements, but the output always contains it.

Is there a way to not have this show up in the output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stumbled upon the solution.

To remove the attributes from the joined table you can use `joinTableAttributes`, like so:

```
user.getProjects({
    attributes: ['id', 'title'],
    joinTableAttributes: []
})
.then(function(projects) {
    res.json(projects)
})
```

By doing that, it will remove the (see OP) output of the user_project table, and the result is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Test Project",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Another one",
  }
]
```

Comment: Cool, Good to know

Comment: Must admit that it is nicely hidden in the sequelize documentation, only single sentence about `joinTableAttributes` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following

```
 user.getProjects({
    attributes: ['id', 'title'],
    through: {
        attributes: []
    }
})
.then(function(projects) {
    res.json(projects)
})
```

Comment: I tried it that way, but it still shows the 'user_project' as part of the response.

Comment: Interesting, when I upgrade to sequelize@4.0.0-2 it should work, but then 'getProjects' is not defined.

Comment: I tried that method on `sequelize` 4.37.6 but it doesn't remove the joined attributes, in fact only `joinTableAttributes` from the other answer was the one to work on the version i am working on

Answer (score 1):

The only way it works for me is to define the DefaultScope of the middle table as

`{ attributes: [] }`

I am using Sequelize@5

Answer (score 1):

I am using  `sequelize: "^6.18.0"`, joinTableAttributes doesn't work for me .

I just use like :

```
  user.getProjects({
    attributes: ['id', 'title'],
    through: {
        attributes: []
    }
})
```